# Image button in PHP doesn't work properly

Tags: php

I have an image button on my PHP page. I need to execute a piece of code when this button is clicked. I'm trying the following.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
    {
        echo "Do some stuff.";  
    }
?>

<input type="image" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" src="images/btnsubmit.gif">
```

When I click the button `btnSubmit`, the `if` condition should be evaluated to true and the message within the `if` body should be echoed to the web page but the condition is never satisfied when I click this button.

When I change the button type to `type='submit'`, it works. I need to use the `type='image'` anyhow. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

It won't evaluate to true because the input has no value.

```
<input type="image" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" src="images/btnsubmit.gif" value="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use JS for this..
here is a rough code:

```
<input type="image" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" src="images/btnsubmit.gif" onClick="javascript:document.myform.submit()">
```

Hope this helps..